# Data Structure for Exam type app

Tags: oop, object, uml, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to create a test (examination) app. However, I'm having difficulty designing my models. Can somebody suggest a good UML diagram to accommodate the following features:

Hierarchy:

- Module has Unit(s)
- Unit has Exam(s)
- Exam has Question(s)
- Question types: (True or False, Identification, Multiple Choice, Matching Type)

So far this is my original design:
[image: Core Data Design]
With this design I can't accommodate a 'Matching Type' kind of question. In addition, how can I persist my previous exams and easily check correct answers?

Comment: Different questions should be set as SEPARATE questions. Or you are breaking the rules.

Comment: You can draw some inspiration from the plentiful of existing test examination applications, e.g. [MoodleDocs: Database schema introduction](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_schema_introduction). See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: "_Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it_"

Comment: I share xmojmr's concern.  With respect, how do you expect to learn anything if someone else does your work for you?

Comment: Hi @xmojmr : Pardon, I wasn't able to add my initial work. I've added a screenshot of my current work. Hope this can add more information.

Comment: What do double arrows mean? There is no such thing in UML standard.

Comment: @Gangnus This diagram was extracted from CoreData model. Double arrow means 'To Many' relationship

Answer (score 1):

You can create class diagram like this (created with [SPARX Enterprise architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/))

[image]

But associations between classes depend on functional requirements. E.g. One Exam belongs only to 1 particular Unit in this example, but you may need Exam that can belong to 0..N different Units. So this is just an example.

Also the way how to persist and check answers depends on further functional requirements. The simplest thing would be to store the Student's Answers with a link to a particular Question.

---

Adding matching type question complicates things a bit, here are few ideas:

[image]

The model uses generalization - `Option` is an abstract class with two inherited classes `ListOption` and `MatchingTypeOption`. When you need to store details about answers the similar must be done with `SelectedOption` because you need to store selected pairs of options for matching type.

But you can also store just info `was the answer correct - yes/no`.

Comment: The question-question type piece is an example how it should not be done. What do you have classes and Interfaces for?

Comment: What interfaces? UML classes could be e.g. mapped to SQL tables.

Comment: THe good style of OOP programming insists on use of interfaces/abstract classes as abstractions instead of TYPE/MODE or similar things. BTW, TYPE has its meaning already.

Comment: When you map your classes (analytical model) to SQL database (technological implementation), how do you map interfaces? `Type` and `QuestionType` is not the same.

Comment: @VDohnal In the first diagram, in 'Answer' entity, are you referring to the available choices/answers for a specific exam? Or the answer made by the student?

Comment: Answer by student. But it is just a very basic example which needs to je adjusted according to additional requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure, how to connect two classes, think, if you should use one more class between them.

[image]

Comment: I believe that a good class model should contain only classes that are really necessary for the system functionality and nothing more. So add extra class only when you are absolutely sure that required relation is M:N.

Comment: @VDohnal Or when some necessary subject from the task/real life is missed. (we should differ answer given by a student and answer set as a correct one). Also if we are in OOP, we should use classes for polymorphism, not modes/variants. And notice, the word Type is already has its meaning, do not use it in other way!

Comment: @VDohnal  A good class model is such model that will make your classes small and simple. Your task is not to make small the model itself!

Comment: I see we are having an interesting debate here :) I must say that having several classes generalized to one interface (Question) without specifying what attributes or relations are specific for theese individual classes seems misleading to me. But we are already very far from OP...